# Specify relative file path

Tags: netbeans, jvm, java, filepath

I'm attempting to connect to [this](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/) API. As part of the instructions, I must add a reference, like so:

```
System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "C:\\WordNet-3.0\\dict\\");
```

That's all well and good, however I would like the path to be relative. The directory is inside my project in the "Resources" folder, as shown below in NetBeans:

[image]

How can the path be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "Resources\\WordNet\\dict\\");
```